# Multiples sentencias en trigger

Tags: mysql

Una tabla **MySQL** (*InnoDB*) debe almacenar los registros de la siguiente manera:

```
id  periodo trans   asiento corr
1011    202108  77  1   1
1012    202108  77  1   2
1013    202108  77  1   3
1014    202108  88  1   1
1015    202108  88  1   2
1016    202108  77  2   1
1017    202108  77  2   2
1018    202108  77  3   1
1019    202108  77  3   2
1020    202108  88  2   1
1021    202108  88  2   2
1018    202109  77  1   1
1019    202109  77  1   2
1020    202109  88  1   1
1021    202109  88  1   2
```

***id*** : Se incrementa según los registros que se inserten.

***asiento*** : Se incrementa por cada grupo ***trans*** dentro de un ***periodo***. Al cambiar de ***periodo*** se reinician los asientos a 1.

***corr*** : Es el correlativo por cada asiento (***periodo*** y ***trans***)

Los campos que se ingresan desde **PHP** son ***periodo*** y ***trans*** y el ***id***, ***asiento*** y ***corr*** deben incrementarse automáticamente.
He tratado de hacer esto en un trigger pero muestra error en la línea 2 y no deja grabar el trigger.

Este es el trigger dentro del editor de phpmyadmin:

```
set new.id=(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM temporal) // incrementa siempre
set new.asiento=(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(asiento),0)+1 FROM temporal WHERE periodo=202109 and trans=77)
set new.corr=(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(0),0)+1 FROM temporal) // inicia siempre en 1 por cada grupo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mensaje de error dice:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `temporal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `periodo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asiento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `corr` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `temporal`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

Quité el segundo `set` para probar sin las condicionales y tampoco funciona.

ACTUALIZACION:
Para probar voy a usar lo siguiente:

```
set new.id=(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM temporal),
set new.corr=(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(corr),0)+1 FROM temporal)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al usar el primero o el segundo por separados, se logra grabar el trigger.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error y por qué terminas los `set` por punto y coma?

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta. Inicialmente lo puse sin (;) estaba probando y lo dejé. Los quito.

Comment: Eso NO es un TRIGGER. Revisa por favor el [tutorial sobre los TRIGGER](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx) para que veas cómo es la sintaxis para crearlos, revisa también el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: Al parecer lo que pretendo hacer no se puede porque no permite realizar eventos multiples en un solo disparador. Tendré que hacerlo desde el código PHP.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *realizar eventos múltiples*?

Comment: Me refiero a los sets que quiero hacer. (Actualicé el post)

Comment: Vos antes del insert, queres cambiar los valores que se van a insertar? No deberias recalcular los nuevos valores que queres despues de hacer el insert?

Comment: es mas.. esto suena a que funcionaria mucho mejor con un procedimiento almacenado que haga todo de una, mas que con un trigger....

Comment: @gbianchi la primera sentencia si la ingreso sola sí funciona. El `id` se incrementa. La tercera sentencia debe iniciar en 1 siempre y se incrementa hasta la cantidad de registros ingresados por tanda. Al tratar de ingresas esas dos sentencias tampoco graba.

Comment: yo no encuentro la funcion ifnull en la documentacion... estas seguro que no esta deprecada? uas nvl en todo caso que haria lo mismo...

Comment: Lo primero es que te faltaría una coma después de cada `set` (excepto el último). Si sigue dando error dinos qué error es. Si es sobre los set, prueba cada sub-consulta SELECT por separado y dinos si funcionan.

Comment: Prueba tus consultas por separado. Es decir, verifica si esta consulta es correcta: `SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM temporal` y también esta: `SELECT IFNULL(MAX(corr),0)+1 FROM temporal`  Puede que alguna de ellas sea errónea y mientras no las resuelvas no podrás hacer que el TRIGGER funcione.

Comment: Por separado funcionan (aunque la segunda no hace lo que quiero, pero funciona), pero al juntarnos sale el mensaje mencionado y no deja grabar el trigger. Creo que esa parte la haré por código. Muchas gracias igual por sus aportes.